# Group and summarise data set by range of age values, gender

Tags: r, group-by, aggregation, binning

I have a data set like below:

```
Card_ID Gender  Age Amount
101000756   M   53  356
101000796   M   54  1009
101000726   F   49  2089
101000769   M   26  4523
101000771   F   76  2098
101000785   F   33  5045
101000825   F   39  6023
101000902   F   62  8009
101000602   M   79  5900
101000352   M   85  4908
101000104   M   30  10008
101000107   F   44  12000
```

I want a summary by Age group and by gender like below:

```
Age  Gender Amount
25 - 40 M   14531
40 - 55 M   1365
55 - 70 M   0
70 - 85 M   10808
25 - 40 F   11068
40 - 55 F   14089
55 - 70 F   8009
70 - 85 F   2098
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you run `dput(YourDataSet)` and add the result to example?

Comment: have a look at the ``cut()`` function...

Comment: You want to **bin** `Age` into `25-40, 40-55, 55-70, 70-85` bins. You can use `cut()`, `dplyr::case_when()` or other commands. The general term is **binning**. (not "sequence of values")

Comment: what is the `Amount` in summary?

Comment: There are many duplicates already: [186 R questions on binning with at least 5 votes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+binning+is%3Aq+score%3A5)

Comment: @SalmanLashkarara: fixed

Comment: Then you want to group-by both Gender and (binned value of) Age, and aggregate the Amount column.

Comment: Thanks guys, here is the code that finally gave me result "summarize(group_by(Data,cut(Data$Age,breaks=seq(25,115,by=15))),sum(Amount))" ....this gives me summary by age...adding gender should not be issue now...thanks your help

Comment: Great. It's perfectly acceptable to post (and accept) your own answer if you solved it.